# How to hide the controls of embedded video?

Tags: javascript, video

Here is the code of embedded video

```
<IFRAME SRC="http://www.mp4upload.com/embed-n5vs0u00hg77.html" allowfullscreen="true" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=380 ></IFRAME>
```

I want to hide or remove the default video controls. Does anyone know how to do it??

Comment: As this is a flash video, you need to check their documentation (`iframe video owner` ) , for hiding controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTML5` video `TAG` documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

```
<video width="640" height="380" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="your_video_path.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the video source yourself, make sure you don't include the `controls` attribute in the `video` source.